# Generate release notes from Subversion

Tags: svn, release-management, release-notes

Is there a way to generate release notes from Subversion comments? Basically I'd be happy if I could just capture the information that you see if you view the log. But if I copy and paste from the log into a text editor, I get a lot of other information I don't want (the lists of files modified with each revision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CL client and run

```
svn log > log.txt
```

and you'll only get the log messages without any additional info.

Answer (score 4):

you should check out [svn2cl](http://arthurdejong.org/svn2cl/), since you likely want to generate these release notes between two revisions, where just redirecting the log will get all the messages - but may get more of them than you actually want.